# WPF create thumbnail by VisualBrush

Tags: wpf, xaml, scale, thumbnails, visualbrush

I have a user control for display thumbnail of a window

UserControl XAML :

```
<Grid x:Name="containerGrid" Margin="0">
        <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="5">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Border.Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Color="White" ShadowDepth="0" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <Border x:Name="containerBorder" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Border.Background>
                    <VisualBrush x:Name="vb" />
                </Border.Background>                
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Once a new window been created, I let above user control display thumbnail of window content by VisualBrush

```
vb.Visual = (Border)Win.Template.FindName("mainBorder", Win);
```

Everything seems work fine...

Opened Window
[image]

Thumbnail

[image]

Until the window size changed by user...
[image]

Thumbnail

[image]

My question is how should I do to let thumbnail width and height always fits my user control (200 X 200) no matter how source(window) size changed??

Many thanks if there is any clue.

SOLVED by set Stretch to Fill and ViewBox to window ActualWidth and ActualHeight

```
<VisualBrush x:Name="vb" Stretch="Fill" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                        <VisualBrush.Viewbox>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{CONV:WidthHeightToRectConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Win.ActualWidth" />
                                <Binding Path="Win.ActualHeight" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </VisualBrush.Viewbox>                        
                    </VisualBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting stretch on your visualbrush.

```
<VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
```

There are other options on stretch but I think Fill will be the one you want.

Comment: I did, it doesn't work, and Fill is the default value of Stretch